# Driver suggestion for AMD Ryzen 5 3550H with Radeon Vega Mobile Gfx

Tags: drivers, kernel, amdgpu, firmware

```
Graphics:
  Card-1: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Baffin [Radeon RX 460/560D / Pro 450/455/460/555/560]
           bus-ID: 01:00.0
           chip-ID: 1002:67ef

  Card-2: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Picasso bus-ID: 04:00.0 chip-ID: 1002:15d8
           Display Server: x11 (X.Org 1.20.8 ) 
           drivers: ati,amdgpu (unloaded: modesetting,fbdev,vesa,radeon)
           Resolution: 1920x1080@60.05hz
           OpenGL: renderer: AMD RAVEN (DRM 3.35.0, 5.4.0-48-generic, LLVM 10.0.0)
           version: 4.6 Mesa 20.0.8 
           Direct Render: Yes
```

This is my inxi output for graphics I use default amdgpu drivers, I have been using ubuntu for the last 2 years now. After kernel 5.4 there are a lot of driver issues with amdgpu.

1. Delayed start with error amdgpu init fatal error
2. possible missing firmwares for amdgpu ... every time i upgrade or do any dkms install

These problems persist on Ubuntu and each of its derivatives .elementary , linux mint , xubuntu ,kali and many more

Any suggestion for drivers . Also, amdgpu pro drivers from amd official site fails to install

should i switch to rocm ?? or any other drivers for my graphics ??

Comment: "Missing firmware" is not a problem at all. The other one may be some kernel issue that can be reported as a bug. You are wrong thinking that you need some drivers.

Comment: Thanks , I have tried fixing missing firmware errors as usual by cloning from git.kernel but problem still persists because the firmware files that are missing are not present in git.kernel and all these missing firmware are of amdgpu